# Cannot figure out how the bounds of a Region work

Tags: javafx-8

I'm currently writing a CAD-like program for logic circuits (it's my first "graphics intensive" program ever). When I place a component on the schematic, let say an AND gate (which is Region class at its root), I want to be able to interact with it (select it, change its properties, etc). So far, so good. I can click on it and everything go well. However, if I click outside of it, the mouse click event still show the component as it source(!).

Digging a bit further, I put some traces in the mouse click handler and found out that `getBoundsInLocal()` and `getBoundsInParent()` return bounds that are around 50% larger than it should be. The `getLayoutBounds()`, `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` do return the correct value.

The pane onto which the components are laid out is a simple `Pane` object, but it uses `setScaleX()` and `setScaleY()` to implement zooming capabilities. I did try to disable them, with no luck.

```java
public abstract class SchematicComponent
        extends Region {
    private Shape graphicShape = null;

    public Shape getGraphicShape() {
        if( isShapeDirty() ) {
            if( graphicShape != null ) {
                getChildren().remove( graphicShape );
            }

            graphicShape = createShape();

            markShapeDirty( false );
            if( graphicShape != null ) {
                getChildren().add( graphicShape );
            }
        }

        return graphicShape;
    }

    abstract protected Shape createShape();
}

abstract public class CircuitComponent
        extends SchematicComponent {
}

abstract public class LogicGate
        extends CircuitComponent {

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();

        Pin outPin;
        final double inputLength = getInputPinsMaxLength();

        // Layout the component around its center.
        // NOTE: I did try to set the center offset to 0 with no luck.
        Point2D centerOffset = getCenterPointOffset().multiply( -1 );

        Shape gateShape = getGraphicShape();
        if( gateShape != null ) {
            gateShape.setLayoutX( centerOffset.getX() + inputLength );
            gateShape.setLayoutY( centerOffset.getY() );
        }

        /* Layout the output pins. */
        outPin = getOutputPin();
        if( outPin != null ) {
            outPin.layout();

            outPin.setLayoutX( centerOffset.getX() + getWidth() );
            outPin.setLayoutY( centerOffset.getY() + getHeight() / 2 );
        }

        /* Compute the first input pin location and the gap between each
           pins */
        double pinGap = 2;
        double y;
        if( getInputPins().size() == 2 ) {
            y = centerOffset.getY() + getHeight() / 2 - 2;
            pinGap = 4;
        }
        else {
            y = centerOffset.getY() + ( getHeight() / 2 ) - getInputPins().size() + 1;
        }

        /* Layout the input pins */
        for( Pin inPin : getInputPins() ) {
            inPin.layout();

            inPin.layoutXProperty().set( centerOffset.getX() );
            inPin.layoutYProperty().set( y );

            y += pinGap;
        }
    }

}

// The actual object placed on the schematic
public class AndGate
        extends LogicGate {

    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth( double height ) {
        // NOTE: computeMin/MaxWidth methods call this one

        double width = getSymbolWidth() + getInputPinsMaxLength();
        double length = 0;

        width += length;

        if( getOutputPin().getLength() > 0 ) {
            width += getOutputPin().getLength();
        }

        return width; // Always 16
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight( double width ) {
        // NOTE: computeMin/MaxHeight methods call this one
        return getSymbolHeight() + getExtraHeight();  // Always 10
    }

    @Override
    protected Shape createShape() {
        Path shape;
        final double extraHeight = getExtraHeight();
        final double inputLength = getInputPinsMaxLength();
        final double outputLength = getOutputPin().getLength();

        /* Width and Height of the symbol itself (i,e, excluding the
           input/output pins */
        final double width = getWidth() - inputLength - outputLength;
        final double height = getHeight() - extraHeight;

        /* Starting point */
        double startX = 0;
        double startY = extraHeight / 2;

        ArrayList<PathElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        elements.add( new MoveTo( startX, startY ) );
        elements.add( new HLineTo( startX + ( width / 2 ) ) );
        elements.add( new ArcTo( ( width / 2 ), // X radius
                                 height / 2, // Y radius
                                 180, // Angle 180°
                                 startX + ( width / 2 ), // X position
                                 startY + height, // Y position
                                 false, // large arc
                                 true ) ); // sweep
        elements.add( new HLineTo( startX ) );

        if( extraHeight > 0 ) {
            /* The height of the input pins is larger than the height of
               the shape so we need to add extra bar on top and bottom of 
               the shape.
             */
            elements.add( new MoveTo( startX, 0 ) );
            elements.add( new VLineTo( extraHeight + height ) );

        }
        else {
            elements.add( new VLineTo( startY ) );
        }

        shape = new Path( elements );
        shape.setStroke( getPenColor() );
        shape.setStrokeWidth( getPenSize() );
        shape.setStrokeLineJoin( StrokeLineJoin.ROUND );
        shape.setStrokeLineCap( StrokeLineCap.ROUND );
        shape.setFillRule( FillRule.NON_ZERO );
        shape.setFill( getFillColor() );

        return shape;
    }
} // End: LogiGate

// SchematicView is the ScrollPane container that handles the events
public class SchematicView
        extends ScrollPane {

    /* Mouse handler inner class */
    private class MouseEventHandler
            implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle( MouseEvent event ) {
        if( event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED ) {
            processMouseClicked( event );
        }
        else { /* ... more stuff ... */ }
     }

    private void processMouseClicked( MouseEvent event ) {
        Object node = event.getSource();
        SchematicSheet sheet = getSheet();

        Bounds local = ( (Node) node ).getLayoutBounds();
        Bounds local1 = ( (Node) node ).getBoundsInLocal();
        Bounds parent = ( (Node) node ).getBoundsInParent();

        // At this point, here is what I get:
        // node.getHeight() = 10    -> Good
        // local.getHeight() = 10   -> Good
        // local1.getHeight() = 15.6499996...   -> Not expected!
        // parent.getHeight() = 15.6500015...   -> Not expected!

        /*... More stuff ... */
    }
}
```

So at this point, I'm running of clues of what is going on. Where do these `getBoundsInXXX()` values come from? They doesn't match with the parent's scale values either. The same goes with `getWidth()`: I get 24.825000... instead of 16.

Looking at this, I understand why clicking outside the component works as if I clicked on it. Its bounds are about 50% bigger than what it should be.

I googled the damn thing and search some doc for almost 2 days now and I'm still baffled. I think I understand that `getBoundsInXXX()` methods do their own computation but could it be off by that much? I don't thing so. My best guess is that it is something inside the `createShape()` method but I just can't figure what it is.

Anyone has a clue of what is going on?

Many thanks for your help.

P.S.: This is my first post here, so hopefully I did it right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found the problem :)

Basically, the `Pin` custom shape was drawn in the negative part of X axis (wrong calculations, my bad!). My best guess is that somehow, Java notices that I drew outside the standard bounds and then added the extra space used to the bounds, hence, adding 50% to width, which matches the length of the `Pin`. Drawing it in the positive region seem to have fixed the problem.

I'm not 100% sure if that is the right answer, but it make sense and it is now working has expected.